# In tikzmath the "random" puts ".0.0" if want negative random number

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath, tikzmath

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\begin{document}
\tikzmath{
  int \foo;
  \foo = random(-16,10);
  print {Foo value: \foo.};
}

\tikzmath{
  int \foo;
  \foo = random(2,10);
  print {Foo value: \foo.};
}
\end{document}
```

Please note the beginning of first line. Is this behavior normal?

[image: Bad result]